# TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in react-redux

Tags: react-redux

I am using axios to create a restful api in my project.Based on the server response I am trying to dispatch an action.

**restful api code**

handleSubmit(e) {

```
console.log("form submit");
e.preventDefault();
const forms=new FormData(e.target);
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/reactLogin",forms).then(res=> {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.props.loginSubmit(res.data);

}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

}

code to dispatch action in react-redux

```
const mapStateProps=(state) => {
    return {
        userLogin:state.loginDetails
    }
}
const mapDispatchProps=(dispatch) => {
    return {

        loginSubmit:(data) => {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.status==1) {
                dispatch(loginSuccess(data.data[0]));
            }
            else {
                dispatch(loginFail(data))
            }
        },

        emailInputBorder:(data) => {
            dispatch(emailBorder(data));
        },
        passwordInputBorder:(data) => {
            dispatch(passwordBorder(data));
        }
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateProps,mapDispatchProps)(Login)
```

when i trying to dispatch an action in my restful api response it shows following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

what the issue here is?

Comment: I'm sure you know that already, but that means 'this' is not defined. you might need to bind 'this' to your handleSubmit function

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a functional component, you can access the `props` directly without using the `this` keyword.

Access the method with something like `props.loginSubmit` directly.

Since I am not able to view your entire file, this is just a pre-assumption. It would be helpful if you could share the entire code.